# TFS 2013: "The Project Process Settings must be configured for this feature to be used" running witadmin

Tags: xml, tfs

I'm trying to update my TFS project's states. I'm able to export the config XML easy enough, but when I run importprocessconfig I receive this message:

```
TF400572: The Project Process Settings must be configured for this feature to be used" running witadmin
```

I know there's not a problem with the XML because I receive the same message when attempting to import unchanged XML.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this: [Configure features after a TFS upgrade](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff432837.aspx) ?

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is about a year old, but I wanted to chime in here. If you are manually adding features to an older process template, I think classicalConditioning's solution will work so long as you have imported all of the new type definitions.  [This](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/add-features-manually#update-categories) article describes how to load the new type definitions, but this is basically the sequence of events:

1. From a command prompt (assuming you have already downloaded the process template you want to upgrade too), `witadmin importwitd /collection:YourProjectCollection /p:"YourProject" /f:"<path to typedefinition xml>"` You will need to do this for each type in the directory
2. When going from TFS 2008 -> 2013, the above will fail when you attempt to load the SharedStep type definition.  you will need to run `witadmin changefield /collection:YourProjectCollection /n:"<System Name>" /name:"new friendly name"` An example of System Name and Friendly Name would be "System.AreaID" and "Area ID", respectively. You will need to do this for a handful of fields.
3. You can now import your new categories as follows `witadmin importcategories /collection:YourProjectCollection /p:"YourProject" /f:"<path to categories xml>"`
4. Once you do this you should be able to follow classicalConditioning's link and configure the process as defined in that article.

Also, I don't know if it matters, but I went through this process with the Microsoft Scrum 2013.5 process template.  Not sure if it would be different for any other template.